# Saving word2vec model results in messed up file

Tags: word2vec

Saving word2vec in the word2vec text format gives a file with weird characters in it.

[image: What the saved word2vec text file looks like]

The contents of the file word2vec is making vectors from.

[image: Cleaned and tokenized text]

I get no errors until I try and use the vector files in an analogy test. The text originally comes from an East African online newspaper.

My code:

```
word2vec = gensim.models.Word2Vec(all_words, min_count=3, workers = 2)
save_as_1 = "daily_nation_" + str(subject) + "_" + str(startyr) + "_" + str(endyr) + "_vectors.txt"
save_as_2 = "daily_nation_" + str(subject) + "_" + str(startyr) + "_" + str(endyr) + "_vectors.bin"
word2vec.wv.save_word2vec_format(save_as_1, binary = "FALSE")
word2vec.wv.save_word2vec_format(save_as_2, binary = "TRUE")
vocabulary = word2vec.wv.vocab
print("Vectors: ")
print(vocabulary)
sim_words = word2vec.wv.most_similar('woman')
print("Words most similar to woman are: " + str(sim_words))
```

I  want to  create proper text files of the embeddings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide a boolean to the `binary` argument:

```
word2vec.wv.save_word2vec_format(save_as_1, binary = False)
```

Your code does not work since any non empty string evaluates to `True`.